# Deploying with TeamCity

Tags: .net, desktop-application, setup-deployment, teamcity-7.0

Our team started a solution which consists of 4 projects - a desktop app, 2 web app, a win- and a web-services.

We decided to use TeamCity as a CI server and decided to use it as for building setup packages (nightly builds). Google shows me a lot of articles on how to deploy web application, using .zip packages - but no one upon how to create a msi or setup.

Also no clues on how to do the same for a non-web project - as are desktop apps, web- and win -services.

Have anyone used TeamCity for building and deploying a non-web application?

Comment: Did you think about ClickOnce ?http://weblogs.asp.net/lkempe/archive/2009/11/11/automating-publish-of-clickonce-with-teamcity.aspx

Comment: 2remi - not in this life... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose the Dao way - NAnt+TeamCity - NAnt script make the [checkout/update from SVN](http://byatool.com/lessons/using-subversion-with-nant-automated-checkouts-from-config-file/), builds the solutions, prepare setup by compiling setup projects...

and thats all...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't use Teamcity to build Windows non-web application. Mostly Java web or standalone applications and iOS & Android applications

In teamcity, there is a `"Visual Studio (sln)`" build step type, try to see if you can utilize that.

Or I will investigate if I can build the msi and setup using `MSBuild`, if it turns out to be possible, I can add a `MSBuild` type build step in teamcity which creates the msi or setup.

Or I can imagine myself trying to create a `cmd` or `powershell` script to build the msi using [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/), and install `WiX` on my teamcity build agents.

Then in the Teamcity project setup, add a build step (type `Command Line` or `Powershell`) that calls this build script.

Comment: According to Teamcity's [Supported Platforms and Environments] (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Supported+Platforms+and+Environments#SupportedPlatformsandEnvironments-BuildRunners), `Visual Studio (sln)` build step requires VS.NET installed on build server. But `MSBuild` build type requires only `.Net Framework` installed. Can you use the `MSBuild` build type if for some reason you can not install VS.NET on the build server?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Visual Studio (VS 2012) build runner.  I have a parameter, system.OutDir, which I specify an output directory.

Then I have a powershell script run which robocopys the contents of system.OutDir to our NAS, and overwrites the web.config from the build output with a different web.config containing the correct connection strings.

Very easy to setup - and you don't have to deal with web.config transformations.